# Would this alteration safeguard the resulting theory from inconsistency?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, theories-of-arithmetic

> If we replace "Emergence" axiom in the theory $T$ presented at posting "[What is the set theory synonymous with this order-set theory?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/461871/95347)" with the following axiom, call the resulting theory $T^*$, then would theory $T^* - {\sf Fin + I}$ escape the inconsistency argument presented in the [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/461895/95347) to that posting?

$ \textbf {Emergence*: } \\\forall i \in \omega \, ( \max_i x < \max_i y \land  \forall n \in \{ i-1, \dots, -1\}\,( \max_n x = \max_n y ) \to x < y) $

Where, $ \max_{-1}x = \varnothing \\\max_0 x = \min y: \forall m \in x \, (m < y) \\  \max_{n+1} x = P_x(\max_n x);  \text { if } n > -1$

Where $P_x$ is defined as: $ a=P_x(b) \iff a \in x \land a < b \land \not \exists c \in x: a < c < b$

$\omega$ is the set of all Von Neumann naturals.

"$\max_i x < \max_i y$" is defined as: $ \exists b  \, \bigl( b=\max_i y \land \forall a \, (a= \max_i x \to a < b) \bigr)$

While, "$\max_i x = \max_i y$" is defined as: $\exists a \exists b \, (a=\max_i x \land b=\max_i y \land a=b)$

The point is that theory $T$ is synonymous with $T^*$, and the theory $T - {\sf Fin + I}$ was inconsistent, so would that alternation safeguard $T^* - \sf Fin + I $ from that inconsistency argument?

> More positively put, does $\sf ZFC$ [or a suitable extension of it] prove ${\sf Con}(T^* - {\sf Fin + I})$?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is to the positive.

I think the refered to inconsistency [argument](https://mathoverflow.net/a/461895/95347) would be bypassed here since this principle implies a restricted form of Emergence, that is:

$\max \, (x \setminus y ) < \max \, (y \setminus x) \land \\ fin (\{ z \in y \mid z > \max (y \setminus x) \}) \\\to x < y$

Where, "$fin$" means "is finite", defined in the usual manner as existence of a bijection with some Von Neumann natural. This would prevent the $<$-descent mentioned in that argument, since we only have finite elements of $y$ above $\max \, ( y\setminus x)$. However, $\sf Emergence^*$ also implies the principle:

$\lim x < \lim y \to x < y$

where, $\lim a = \min b: \forall m \in a \, (m < b)$

It appears to me that $\sf ZFC$ can prove the consistency of the theory in question, since we can take $V_{\omega+\omega}$ and fix a rank respective well ordering $<$ over it. So, $\sf ZGC$ would be captured in it. Now, the first four axioms of $T^* - \sf Fin + I$ are easily seen to be captured, what remains is to capture $\sf Emergence^*$. To do that, we take the relation $\prec$ on sets in $V_{\omega+\omega}$, defined as: $$ x \prec y \iff \rho(x) < \rho(y)$$, where, "$\rho$" is the rank function. Now, $\prec$ is not a well-ordering, yet it is a well-founded partial order binary relation. At each $V_{\alpha < \omega+\omega}$ stage we begin with relation $ (\prec \restriction V_\alpha)$, call it $\prec_\alpha$ for short, now, we want to add further pairs to that set in order to get the set $\prec_\alpha^+$  in the following manner: any sets $a,b \in V_\alpha$ of rank $\alpha$: if $\lim a \prec^+_{\alpha-1}\lim b$ then we add the pair $\langle a,b\rangle$ to elements of $\prec_\alpha^+$ , now if $a,b$ have the same limits (i.e. the same $ \max_0 $ values, and so the same $\max_1$ values if those exist), then if $\max_2 a \prec^+_{\alpha-1}\max_2 b$, we add $\langle a,b \rangle$ to elements of $\prec_\alpha^+$, if these are also the same then if $\max_3 a \prec^+_{\alpha-1}\max_3 b$ we add $\langle a,b \rangle$ to elements of $\prec_\alpha^+$, and so on if we have $\max_i a = \max_i b$ for all $i < j$ and we have $\max_j a \prec^+_{\alpha-1}\max_j b$, then $\langle a,b \rangle$ would be added to elements of $\prec_\alpha^+$; if $\max_i a = \max_i b$ for all $i$ values, then $\langle a,b \rangle$ is added to elements of $\prec_\alpha^+$ only if we have $a < b$, then we add all elements of the piror $\prec^+_{\lambda < \alpha}$ to the elements of $\prec^+_\alpha$. We set $\prec^+_\alpha$ to be the intersection of all such sets, and so we have:$\prec^+_\alpha = \bigcup_{\lambda< \alpha} \! \prec^+_\lambda$ . All of the above can be easily done in $\sf ZFC$. So, we get to capture all axioms of $T^* -\sf Fin + I$ in the strucutre $(V_{\omega+\omega}, = \restriction V_{\omega+\omega}, \in \restriction V_{\omega+\omega}, \prec_{\omega+\omega}^+)$.