# What is the theory of statements with a provably *bounded* realizer (according to PA)?

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory, constructive-mathematics, theories-of-arithmetic, realizability

$\let\T\mathrm\def\kr{\mathrel{\mathbf r}}$This is a follow up to [Kleene realizability in Peano arithmetic](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/323964/kleene-realizability-in-peano-arithmetic).

We can summarize the results from Emil Jeřábek's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/323988/65915) as follows:

\begin{gather*}
T_1 = \{ \phi : \exists n. \T{PA} \vdash \overline n \kr \phi \} = \T{HA}+\T{ECT}_0+\T{MP} \\
T_3 = \{ \phi : \T{PA} \vdash \exists n. n \kr \phi \} = \T{HA}+\T{ECT}_0+\T{MP}+\T{SLEM}
\end{gather*}

where $\T{SLEM}$ is excluded middle for sentences.

My question is about finding a third theory, one for which PA can find a *bound* on the realizer (but not necessarily the exact value).

$$T_2 = \{ \phi : \exists k. \T{PA} \vdash \exists n < \overline k. n \kr \phi \} = \T{?}$$

Clearly we have $T_1 \subseteq T_2 \subseteq T_3$. We can also show that they are distinct.

$T_2$ proves excluded middle for all negated sentences, but $T_1$ does not. In particular, $T_2 \vdash \lnot \operatorname{Con}(\T{PA}) \lor \lnot \lnot \operatorname{Con}(\T{PA})$.

For any numeral $n$, $T_3$ can prove that the $n$th [busy beaver number $\operatorname{BB}(n)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver) exists because $\T{PA}$ proves it exists and knows how to turn it into a realizer (a different realizer for each $n$). $T_2$ is unable to prove this when $n$ is sufficiently large (say, [8000 or more](https://scottaaronson.blog/?p=2725)) because for any numeral $k$, PA can't prove that $\operatorname{BB}(n) < k$.

So, what is $T_2$?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek $\let\T\mathrm\def\kr{\mathrel{\mathbf r}}$in that answer one of the steps was "Since $\exists x\,(x\kr\phi)$ is a sentence, this implies
$\T{HA+MP+SLEM}\vdash\exists x\,(x\kr\phi).$". How does that work using excluded middle just for negated sentences?

Comment: (fyi, the lower bound of 8000 was lowered by bachelor student Johannes Riebel [to 745](https://www.ingo-blechschmidt.eu/assets/bachelor-thesis-undecidability-bb748.pdf) (from an earlier bound of 748).)

Comment: The 745 bound is for ZFC; it should be considerably less for PA. In particular, if you take the adjunctive set theory plus the induction schema as in https://mathoverflow.net/a/461632 (you don't need the empty set axiom if you formulate induction in the right way, and I think you can make do without extensionality while keeping the same consistency strength), the axioms should have a shorter description than ZF.

Comment: There may also be ways of optimizing the proof system. I’m a bit puzzled by the unusual quantifier axioms, but the propositional part can be definitely shortened by using Meredith’s single axiom ((((p→q)→(¬r→¬s))→r)→t) → ((t→p)→(s→p)). Or, use $\bot$ as primitive instead of $\neg$, and take Łukasiewicz’s axiom $((p\to q)\to r)\to((r\to p)\to(s\to p))$ and $\bot\to p$.

Comment: (I’m sorry for the off-topic comments. I swear I will stop.) Here’s a fun way of axiomatizing ZFfin (without regularity, but including extensionality), which should lead to a particularly short description: $\forall x,y\,\exists z\,\forall t\,(t\in z\leftrightarrow(t\in x\oplus t=y))$ + the schema $\forall x\,(\forall y\subsetneq x\,\phi(y)\to\phi(x))\to\phi(x)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\let\T\mathrm\def\kr{\mathrel{\mathbf r}}\let\LOR\bigvee$The same argument as in my linked answer shows that
$$T_2=\T{HA+ECT_0+MP+SWLEM},$$
where
$$\T{SWLEM}=\{\neg\phi\lor\neg\neg\phi:\text{$\phi$ sentence}\}.$$
You already observed that $T_2$ includes $T_1+\T{SWLEM}$.

On the other hand, assume $\T{PA}\vdash\exists x\le\overline n\,x\kr\phi$, and let $\psi(x)$ be a negative formula equivalent to $x\kr\phi$ in $\T{HA+MP}$. Then $\T{PA}\vdash\LOR_{m\le n}\psi(\overline m)$, thus $\T{HA}$ proves its double negation translation, which is equivalent to $\neg\neg\LOR_{m\le n}\psi(\overline m)$ as $\psi$ is negative. Consequently, $\T{HA+SWLEM}\vdash\LOR_{m\le n}\neg\neg\psi(\overline m)$, i.e., $\LOR_{m\le n}\psi(\overline m)$, using negativity again, thus $\T{HA+SWLEM+MA}\vdash\LOR_{m\le n}\overline m\kr\phi$, and $\T{HA+SWLEM+MA+ECT_0}\vdash\phi$.